# User Prompt to Play Again Not Working

Tags: c

i made a simple snake game below. everything works fine however i am trying to implement a feature that allows the user to play the game again by entering 1.

I am currently using do.. while... loop for the game

However, Here is the problem, the program does restart upon entering 1, but
none of the characters (tx,jx,etc) spawns, and the game simply goes infinitely looping in the background (upon exiting there is a x amount of printf("Number of juju...."), printf("ripperoni") printed in the background

Help is appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "display.h"
#include "move.h"
#include "place.h"
#define MAX 799
#define DEAD 0
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
int main()
{
//initialize variables
struct pos {         //positions
    int fx[MAX];
    int fy[MAX];
    int tx;
    int ty;
    int jx;
    int jy;
} pos;

struct score {      //scores
    int move;
    int F;
    int J;
} score;

int d,q,i,k,f,followc;
int p;
char *z="Number of Jujus collectd ";
char *y="The number of followers ";
do {
    score.F=score.J = score.move = 0;
    i=k=f=followc=0;
    draw_map();
    place(&pos.tx,&pos.ty);
    sleep(1);
    draw_symbol(pos.tx, pos.ty, 'S');
    place(&pos.jx, &pos.jy);
    display_score(score.move);
    debug_wds(5,z);
    debug_wds(8,y);
    debug_num(6,score.J);
    debug_num(9,score.F);
    while(d!=DEAD && q != 'q' && q != 'Q')
    {
        pos.fx[i]=pos.tx;  //store timmy's position in follower
        pos.fy[i]=pos.ty;  //store timmy's position in follower
        draw_symbol(pos.jx, pos.jy, '$');
        display_score(score.move);
        debug_wds(5,z);
        debug_num(6,score.J);
        debug_wds(8,y);
        debug_num(9,score.F);
        q = move(&pos.tx, &pos.ty); //move timmy
        score.move++;
        draw_symbol(pos.tx,pos.ty,'S');  //update timmy's position
        if((pos.tx ==pos.jx)&&(pos.ty == pos.jy))  //if timmy collects a juju
        {

            score.J++; //update juju score
            score.F++; //update follower score
            display_score(score.move);
            place(&pos.jx,&pos.jy);
            followc++; //update follower count
        }

        for (f=0,k=i+1-followc; f<followc; f++,k++) //check to see if timmy is same position as followers
        {
            if(pos.tx==pos.fx[k]&&pos.ty==pos.fy[k])
            {
                d=DEAD;
            }
            draw_symbol(pos.fx[k],pos.fy[k],'O'); //draw followers
        }
        i++;
    }
    clear_screen();
    printf("Number of Jujus = %d\n", score.J);   
    printf("Ripperoni... You really need to update your server(s)..*___*\n");
    printf("Enter 1  to keep playing\n");
    scanf("%d",&p);
} while(p==1);

}
```

Comment: Your problem is that console input is line-buffered, and your scanf() calls are not consuming the entire line so return immediately.. There are numerous duplicated on SO - search "scanf infinite loop".

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out
Need to initialize d!=DEAD again so that it is not dead